# How I can find out which page links to a broken URL?

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler, broken-links

How I can find out which page links to a broken URL when the user agent isn't sending a referrer?

I'm getting 100+ requests to this URL on my site per day:
/controls/WebService/WebService.asmx

...but the actual URL is:
/WebService/WebService.asmx

I could just URL Rewrite one to the other, but I'd rather figure out where the "controls" reference is coming in. I do have a folder called that, with some controls which use the web service, but if I view the source, there's never any mention of the "/controls/" folder...  Usually, no referrer shows up in  Elmah logs for the 404, but even when it does I can't see a problem on the page as the URL to the webservice page is correct.

I've run three different crawlers on the site and they never find any issues so I suspect it's being caused by something with the intelligence to parse (or even execute) JavaScript or something. The fact that the "controls" folder really does exist, makes me think it's likely there's a genuine error somewhere rather than it simply being a bug in the crawler software.

Comment: Isn't it possible that someone is just trying to find a vulnerability on your site?

Comment: Try enabling the IIS log and check the user agent for those requests

Comment: can you share the domain for the site?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a file inside the controls directory that is trying to reference that web service by relative path. Use ~/Webservice/Webservice.asmx (if from a .net control) or simply /Webservice/Webservice.asmx

Comment: Yeah I'm certain it's that, but the problem is finding it! There are hundreds of pages on this 12 year old site.  I simply cannot find it - and no crawlers I've run myself have found the problem.

Comment: can you search your solution for Webservice/Webservice.asmx ?